# Geolocate stores inside a mall?

Tags: geolocation

OpenStreetMap lists the malls in Albuquerque, but not the stores 
inside these malls.

Using the in-mall map/directory, wouldn't it be easy to add stores 
inside the mall?

Is anyone doing this?

Of course, a more fun way would be to visit every store in the mall, 
but using the mall directory seems more efficient.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this question: [Are there any Indoor GIS platforms?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7158/are-there-any-indoor-gis-platforms)

Comment: Bing Maps has Malls with Stores - http://binged.it/L2OkqN (Cottonwood Mall, Albuquerque, NM) you can use the Bing Maps API v7 to customise your own map application

Comment: I'm guessing that Bing Maps doesn't have the same licensing as OSM, though? I'm wanting to add/find the data with some Creative Commons type license, ideally OSM itself.