# How to convert an image of a floor plan into data that I can work with?

Tags: routing, mapping, indoor

This is more of a research question. I'm looking for aways of converting an image of a floor plant into data that I can work somehow. The end goal is to something similar to this: http://indoorosm.uni-hd.de/3d/.

I want something that allows me to store rooms and corridors informations, and then use it to trace routes between them.

It would be really helpful is someone can point me in the right direction, because the more I search the more different technologies I find, and I don't know which on would serve best my goals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JOSM you can use the PicLayer plugin an load your raster image in and digitise the data into vector indoorOSM format.

[image]

It will not be a 5 minute process you will have to plan a few hours into create the JOSM project and digitising will the time consuming part.

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/IndoorOSM#PicLayer

JOSM is downloaded from
https://josm.openstreetmap.de/

Answer (score 2):

You can find a tutorial using qgis here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DSU0kvXIaPQ
The idea is to project the image of the floor plan on a map and then draw polygons on top of it.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there is a magic tool to turn floor plans into usable maps for routing.

Have a look at [Seeking a GIS for indoor mapping and direction finding](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29134/seeking-a-gis-for-indoor-mapping-and-direction-finding?rq=1) for pointers of how to create something that works.